# How to remove elements of a list, if that elements are not on another list

Tags: r, list

Basically, I have a company list (Marked as list A), and I have a large checklist (Marked as list B). I want to query that if elements of list A are also in list B. Some identical companies have slight difference, so I have to use fuzzy matching. Luckily, I have successfully found the elements that are in A but not in B. But I do not know how to remove it without causing chaos. (It seems that it easily causes boundary error)

```
company <- read.table(text = "
           CompanyName
          'MERCK SHARP & DOHME CORPORATION'
          'GILEAD SCIENCES INC'
          'BOEHRINGER INGELHEIM PHARMACEUTICALS, INC.'
          'ABBVIE, INC.'
          'JANSSEN SCIENTIFIC AFFAIRS, LLC'
          'ASAHI INTECC CO., LTD.'
   ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Report <- c('MERCK ','BOEHRINGER INGELHEIM','ROCHE','ASAHI')
sapply(lapply(Report, function(x) agrepl(x, company$CompanyName, max.distance=0.1)), max)
```

Above is my reproducible data and my fuzzying matching code, which returns

```
[1] 1 1 0 1
```

But I do not know how to remove the company on that 0 position. 
Is running loop on each element a good idea?
I want my result to be

```
'MERCK ','BOEHRINGER INGELHEIM','ASAHI'
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to get as a final result. Could you explain in more details?

Comment: Ok, I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

I defined the following function which return the item form `Report` that match the z item

```
myfunc = function(z){Report[which(lapply(Report,function(y){agrepl(y,z,max.distance = 0.1)})%>%unlist)]}
```

And then apply in turn to each element of your list. I used `unlist` and the pipe symbol `%>%` from magrittr package to convert list structures to vectors.

```
lapply(company$CompanyName,myfunc) %>% unlist
```

In case you want report to be a variable, in order to use the function for different reports, you could define the function

```
myfunc2 = function(z,report){report[which(lapply(report,function(y){agrepl(y,z,max.distance = 0.1)})%>%unlist)]}
```

and then call with Report as and additionnal parameter  to the lapply

```
lapply(company$CompanyName,myfunc2,Report) %>% unlist
```

Comment: Well, if I have a list of reports, can I insert your function to a loop?

Comment: @Cooper I modified my answer to handle this case.